# How to delete related data from child table when I delete specific data from parent table in DB using the delete button in windows form c#

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have many tables in this database. Two of them being Student and StudentAttendance.
In Student table, Id is the primary key which is auto-generated and in the StudentAttendance table
AttendanceId is the primary key and StudentId is foreign key. Now the requirement is that If I delete any student by giving its registration number in the textbox and then clicking the delete button then student record with this id should also get deleted from the StudentAttendance table.
I cannot do this with CASCADE DELETE. I have to do this with a query.
I am trying this code but this is giving me error and not working.

```
private void studentDeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var con = Configuration.getInstance().getConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Student Where RegistrationNumber = @RegistrationNumber", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationNumber", addStudentRegTextbox.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Delete from StudentAttendance Where StudentId = id", con);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record has been Deleted successfully!");
```

[image: StudentTable]
}

Comment: You can both together with a stored procedure, or a trigger, or a session from your client that executes both DML statements itself in a transaction (all of these should be in a transaction) of a CASCADE DELETE.  Note: it's generally *easier* to delete the children *first* and then the parent (in part because of typical foreign key constraints), but you can do it either way.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, check and make sure your mysql database uses InnoDB engine;
- Then, check if you have set the physical foreign-key relation. Theoretically you should add this sql sentence when you create your child table:

```sql
ADD CONSTRAINT `atten_stu_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`StudentId`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Maintain the foreign key relation by the code:

```
private void studentDeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var con = Configuration.getInstance().getConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from StudentAttendance Where StudentId = id", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Delete from Student Where RegistrationNumber = @RegistrationNumber", con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationNumber", addStudentRegTextbox.Text);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record has been Deleted successfully!");
  }
```

Comment: I cannot make any changes in the design of the tables

Comment: Sorry, I think I just misunderstood your words. It's easy to solve the problem——Switch the order of the two lines of query code.

Comment: You cannot delete any record of the parent table if its primary key is referenced by its child table as foreign key. Or you will break the consistency of the relation.

Answer (score 0):

yur code should work fine but you are missing the "@" for the id in the second delete and you can add parametrised to your sql to avoid sql injection

```
 private void studentDeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    var con = Configuration.getInstance().getConnection();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Student Where RegistrationNumber = @RegistrationNumber", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationNumber", addStudentRegTextbox.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Delete from StudentAttendance Where StudentId = @id", con);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", addStudentRegTextbox.Text);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record has been Deleted successfully!");
```

Comment: But i am not taking id in textbox as Ive mentioned it is auto-generated

Comment: you can delete based on any giving values,first try to delete record with the foreign key then delete it from wherever it is primary key